# How to join two overlapping lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, stroke

I am new to design. There are similar questions but none of those solve the problem.

I have the two-line like T shape which is composed of a vertical and a horizontal bar.

I need to join those lines.

[image]

These are in two separate layer

[image]

How to make these two into a single shape?

Edit:- let my state my exact expectation

let's have the following diagram:-

[image]

now, all the vertical line and horizontal line and outside box are not connected

I want to color the section inside the diagram, like this:-

[image]

and now finally separate the sections. like so:-

[image]

Note:- this is not white stroke all the colored are different section

All of this I have done in MS Paint to demonstrate.

The reason I am doing any of this because I am making one character in illustrator and want to animate, I would appreciate suggestion about the best way to make the character/assets
so that it can be animated in aftereffects.

I have given the example of the grid, important point is that has overlapping,

This is exactly I am working on:-

[image]

so, this I have started with the overlapping lines and with the `live paint bucket` i have colored the section and turned the `stroke` to `none` and now want to separate the section as you can identify by the color like maybe separate the hair, band, face, etc..

Now, most probably I will use the `Scissor Tool` but may not be the best solution. what could be the best approach?

Comment: There is no solution for your problem since its impossible to join a t segment. The drawing model just dont work that way. It only has features it strictly needs for drawing all possible shapes. being able to do t intersections is not one of those requirements. Care to clarify your need

Comment: Also we dont call these layers we call them paths. You still have just one layer. The reason the palette is called layers is just because the view got eventually expaned to show whats in the layers,.

Comment: You *can* Group them (Cntrl-G) and that allows them to manipulated as a unit, which depending upon what you meant by "solve the problem" may address your root issue. As @joojaa has asked - can you clarify what you actually need to accomplish here?

Comment: @joojaa - yup, true enough - ***but*** they'll be in a containing element clearly labelled "<Group> that has to be *manually expanded* to see the sub-elements, so it *may* be "readable" to OP as being an item. OP hasn't yet addressed your clarification request, so I've no solid idea what "the problem" is they feel the other similar questions don't solve... I know for many newbies to Illustrator (or other vector apps) the idea that individual paths show up in a layers palette can be confusing / frustrating: for me I find it useful and powerful. I name 'em all for clarity in big illustrations.

Comment: @GerardFalla it owuldnt be confusin if the palette wasnt named layers. It could be easy to solved by calling the panel something else.

Comment: I don't know what it's not a requirement, it seems basic. I just want to color out the different sections of the region made by the overlapping line. and to be able to segregate the section.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha if you look at what you do you actually want to make are squares. In your end result there is no T section.  It might be needed by your thinking but not the software. Simply there is no need for non manifold surfaces to color things. Your job as operator of software is to convert what you think into how the software needs it.

Comment: This is an example of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You know what you want, but don't know how to do it, so you made up solution that you thought would solve it but wouldn't, and then asked about how to solve that problem instead of the real problem. Then finally after your last edit we discover what you really want.  I've brought this to your attention because it's a common problem users have when asking questions here, and so it's good to be aware of this for future questions. Always begin a question with what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Still no need for T intersections.

Comment: @BillyKerr you are correct, I will take care of that, the reason it could end up in the XY problem because, sometimes the user can paste their entire design, and just paste the abstract problem.

Comment: @joojaa the T problem arises when the faces are built with the overlapping lines, at each intersection there is T, hence like an MS Paint I thought those line need to connected so that I can paint the section and separate as required,

Comment: Well now you know that if you ever have a problem where you need a t joint then your not trying to solve a vector graphics problem but some problem unrelated to to graphics as it can be mathematically proven that theres no case where it actually happens. You on the otherhand may have a application unrelated to graphics but then you can just replace that with 3 lines. Ofr separate shapes. Next step is to recognize that if you dont work for a print application then all shapes should overlap the next one ;) (otherwise you get conflation artifacts)

Comment: By the way you would be happier if you would't think of vector graphics as drawing but rather cutting with scissors its more applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now that we know what you need to do....

Shapebuilder tool will accommodate your workflow proposal very nicely.

Here's your matrix drawn with single lines, grouped via <kbd>Cntrl-G</kbd>, and the Shapebuilder Tool selected:
[image]

Here's Shapebuilder doing its thing, as area by area is selected and then coloured up:
[image]

All areas coloured up now:
[image]

That whole group selected and then Object>Expand selected:
[image]

I select one black element from the edge of the figure and then choose Select>Same>Fill & Stroke adn then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> nuking all the black elements:
[image]

And I then manually shifted them a bit so you could see they are in fact separate elemetns as requested.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: To b honest OP could have drawn squares too.

Comment: my problem is not to get the square, this was just to explain what I wanted to do with the overlapping line. see the updated question,

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you cannot join lines in Illustrator, you can only join points (anchors).

Depending on your end purpose, you could however turn these into objects via 'Path > Outline Stroke', then 'Unite' via the 'Pathfinder' panel.

Be advised this will turn your lines into a single object, and you won't be able to edit the thickness of the stroke anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In response to the question being updated, there are easier ways to achive a basic grid like that:

- just draw rectangles, with no strokes, forget about strokes
- Alt+drag to duplicate the rectangles and adjust by having Smart Guides turned on (if you need perfect alignment between each rectangle)
- add color as needed to each rectangle